# Kotlin map not working with List of String

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I have been working on code where I have to generate all possible ways to the target string. I am using the below-mentioned code.

Print Statement:

```
println("---------- How Construct -------")
    println("${
        window.howConstruct("purple", listOf(
            "purp",
            "p",
            "ur",
            "le",
            "purpl"
        ))
    }")
```

Function Call:

```
fun howConstruct(
        target: String,
        wordBank: List<String>,
    ): List<List<String>> {

        if (target.isEmpty()) return emptyList()

        var result = emptyList<List<String>>()

        for (word in wordBank) {
            if (target.indexOf(word) == 0) {    // Starting with prefix
                val substring = target.substring(word.length)
                val suffixWays = howConstruct(substring, wordBank)
                val targetWays = suffixWays.map { way ->
                    val a = way.toMutableList().apply {
                        add(word)
                    }
                    a.toList()
                }

                result = targetWays

            }
        }

        return result
    }
```

Expected Output:-
[['purp','le'],['p','ur','p','le']]

Current Output:-
[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost working; only a couple of small changes are needed to get the required output:

- If the target is empty, return `listOf(emptyList())` instead of `emptyList()`.
- Use `add(0, word)` instead of `add(word)`.

The first of those changes is the important one. Your function returns a list of matches; and since each match is itself a list of strings, it returns a list of lists of strings. Once your code has matched the entire target and calls itself one last time, it returned an empty list — i.e. no matches — instead of a list *containing* an empty list — meaning one match with no remaining strings.

The second change simply fixes the order of strings within each match, which was reversed (because it appended the prefix *after* the returned suffix match).

---

However, there are many others ways that code could be improved. Rather than list them all individually, it's probably easier to give an alternative version:

```
fun howConstruct(target: String, wordBank: List<String>
    ): List<List<String>>
= if (target == "") listOf(emptyList())
else wordBank.filter{ target.endsWith(it) } // Look for suffixes of the target in the word bank
            .flatMap { suffix: String ->
                howConstruct(target.removeSuffix(suffix), wordBank) // For each, recurse to search the rest
                    .map{ it + suffix } } // And append the suffix to each match.
```

That does almost exactly the same as your code, except that it searches from the end of the string — matching suffixes — instead of from the beginning. The result is the same; the main benefit is that it's simpler to append a suffix string to a partial match list (using `+`) than to prepend a prefix (which is quite messy, as you found).

However, it's a lot more concise, mainly because it uses a functional style — in particular, it uses `filter()` to determine which words are valid suffixes, and `flatMap()` to collate the list of matches corresponding to each one recursively, as well as `map()` to append the suffix to each one (like your code does). That avoids all the business of looping over lists, creating lists, and adding to them. As a result, it doesn't need to deal with mutable lists or variables, avoiding some sources of confusion and error.

I've written it as an expression body (with `=` instead of `{ … }`) for simplicity. I find that's simpler and clearer for short functions — this one is about the limit, though. It might fit as it an extension function on String, since it's effectively returning a transformation of the string, without any side-effects — though again, that tends to work best on short functions.

There are also several small tweaks. It's a bit simpler — and more efficient — to use `startsWith()` or `endsWith()` instead of `indexOf()`; `removePrefix()` or `removeSuffix()` is arguably slightly clearer than `substring()`; and I find `== ""` clearer than `isEmpty()`.

(Also, the name `howConstruct()` doesn't really describe the result very well, but I haven't come up with anything better so far…)

Many of these changes are of course a matter of personal preference, and I'm sure other developers would write it in many other ways! But I hope this has given some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your clean code! I was actually learning dynamic programming from FreeCodeCamp, and the instructor Alvin doing the same in a simple way in JS. So, I was trying to build the same using Kotlin.

Just wanted to learn DSA with Kotlin!

Still Thanks a lot!